# html load coming from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

html load coming from NSString.

I have the following problem: I get html code and want to get a webView just not how to do and searched and have not found examples if anyone would be so kind to tell me how you do or would appreciate any example of.

Comment: What do you mean by "get a webView"?  Usually you create one as part of your UI and use it from its view controller.

Comment: `UIWebView` method: `- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIWebView* newWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
[newWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[self.view addSubview:newWebView];
[newWebView release];
```

Comment: I have a NSString custom html and I want to show in a way that's WebView joel?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I already answered your question with sample code.

Comment: It was the above solution.
UIWebView* newWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
[newWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[self.view addSubview:newWebView];
[newWebView release];